# Class Casting Exception in Java

Tags: java, class, exception, casting, classcastexception

I'm having a problem with casting Classes to each other.

To explain it in more detail, take a look at this image.

[image: The Image]

In my code, I do `SkillBase s = new SkillBase();` and then set some values in that class.
Then I try to do `Subclass sub = (Subclass)s;` but when running it it gives a ClassCastException.

I added a small debug part, which checks if it's `instanceof` which returns true.

I've tried the google, saw some questions on here aswell and read them (none of them had an answer that was for me)

So, what do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SkillBase` is not an instance of `Subclass`, so why do you think casting will work? Try with this:

```
SkillBase s = new Subclass();
Subclass sub = (Subclass)s;
```

which will succeed. Also I think you are not correct with `instanceof`, I am certain that:

```
s instanceof Subclass
```

yields `true` in the the code above but `false` in your case.

Thinking in real world terms: you can always cast `Dog` to `Animal` because every dog is an animal<sup>*</sup>, but casting `Animal` to `Dog` might fail since some animals aren't dogs.

<sup>* in fact, compiler does that for you, it is known as polymorphism</sup>

Comment: Actually, that's what I'm doing. Subclass extends SkillBase, so it should be castable right?

Comment: To add: `Subclass` *is a* `SkillBase`. The reverse is **not** true. You can't cast the parent class to a child.

Comment: @Lolmewn: I added some real-life example, have a look.

Comment: After the edit I understand :) Thanks a lot, I will do some re-fractoring!

Answer (score 1):

You can only up-cast i.e. assign sub classes to super class references. Think of it this way: `Subclass` extends the `Superclass` by adding a new method `f()`. Now `Superclass` **doesn't know** any thing about f() and hence the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using `instanceof` wrong.

The runtime is right to crash, as `SkillBase` is not a `Subclass`.

The other way around is true.

Answer (score 1):

s can't be cast to Subclass because it wasn't instantiated as a Subclass. It is a Skillbase. If you want to use a Subclass why not just instantiate it?

```
Subclass s = new Subclass();
```

You can still set the parameters you want because they hare inherited by Skillbase and the cast is no longer necessary.

Comment: Because I'm in a for loop and would have to check what I am looking at before doing the rest, but this seems like a good option if other stuff fails.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not using casting properly.  A class can always be cast as its parent, but not the other way around.  The concept is that a child class (by definition) knows the structure of the parent, and (by definition) already supports all the signatures in the parent.  Consequently, the parent is a subset of the child.

The inverse, however, is not true.  The parent class knows nothing about the child class and/or whether the child has added extra signatures to its structure.  Consequently, there is no way to tell the compiler to treat the parent as a child and make available all the methods that the child has in the parent.

It layman speak, water (child) is a liquid (parent), but not all liquids are water.  Consequently, any measurements you want to make on liquids (ie: quantity, viscosity, etc) hold true for water as well, but not the other way around (ex: density of water is completely different than density of oil).

So to bring this all back to your situation, you can cast `Subclass` as a `Skillbase` but not the other way around.

```
Subclass instanceof Skillbase == true
(Skillbase) new Subclass() - also valid
(SKillbase) new Sub#2 - also valid
```

etc...